# How to get Deno prompt() to go over 255 characters

Tags: javascript, command-prompt, deno

If you run a `prompt("Paste JSON into here")` in Deno, you can put a maximum of 255 characters.

Is there a method to make it unlimited, or at least get a better reasonable limit without taking on a dependency or looping.

I tried taking on chunks of json through looping prompt() calls, but that would require hitting enter() and adding more complexity to users of program.

Comment: Do you get any error? I can paste more than 255 characters.

Comment: @MisterJojo I explicitly said I'm using "in Deno."

Comment: @BookOfCooks can you post a screenshot, or the error, or the prompt being clipped? What OS? and what Deno version.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande No, it just cuts off at 255 characters. It doesn't <Enter> automatically, I have to press <Enter>. Note, I'm talking about the Deno runtime, not a web browser.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande On windows 11 on the lastest version of deno (updated that about 3 hours ago): https://imgur.com/DKAKHt3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in Deno for Windows
https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/19010

Until it is fixed, as a workaround you could use [Ubuntu on WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) or use the following snippet from @Lenni009 (Who reported the bug)

```
import { readLines } from "https://deno.land/std@0.197.0/io/mod.ts";

async function prompt(promptText) {
    const text = new TextEncoder().encode(`${promptText} `);
    Deno.writeAllSync(Deno.stdout, text);
    const { value: input } = await readLines(Deno.stdin).next();
    return input;
}
```